# using the intel mkl library to solve linear system using direct solver, the dss_create gives exception thrown

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, intel-mkl

The following is a class in my code which solves FEM problem.

The coefficient matrix of the linear system of equations is a sparse one so I am using the [intel mkl direct solver for sparse matrices](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-direct-sparse-solver-dss-interface-routines#7C5F5C27-0E6D-4612-9460-E0F03A20DA83) to solve this system.

The class is used to solve the linear system and I tried it before for a simple problem and it works well by comparing the results with matlab. I am sure that all the links are correct and the configuration is set to be x64

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <mkl.h>
using namespace std;

class Solution
{
private:
    int *row, *col, nelx, nely;
    double *K, *b;
public:
    Solution(double *x, double* xx, int* y, int* z, int ll, int nn) 
    {
        K = x;
        b = xx;
        row = y;
        col = z;
        nelx = ll;
        nely = nn;
    }
    double* f();
};

double* Solution::f()
{
    int n = (nelx + 1)*(nely + 1) * 2, m = 868, l=1;
    double *sol = new double[n];
    int *perm = new int[n];
    _MKL_DSS_HANDLE_t handle;

    MKL_INT opt = MKL_DSS_ZERO_BASED_INDEXING;
    dss_create(handle, opt);

    // dss_define_structure
    opt = MKL_DSS_NON_SYMMETRIC;
    dss_define_structure(handle, opt, row, n, n, col, m);

    // dss_reorder
    opt = MKL_DSS_AUTO_ORDER;
    dss_reorder(handle, opt, perm);

    // dss_factor_real, dss_factor_complex
    opt = MKL_DSS_POSITIVE_DEFINITE;
    dss_factor_real(handle, opt, K);

    // dss_solve_real, dss_solve_complex
    opt = MKL_DSS_REFINEMENT_ON;
    dss_solve_real(handle, opt, b, l, sol);

    return sol;
}
```

When I use the class for the whole code it gives me the following message at the "dss_create" command:

> Exception thrown at 0x000000007750F7E7 (ntdll.dll) in top88_class.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000E0111350228.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
There was an mistake in some declaration in another class which affects this class I don't know why.